# Click through multiple plots within each iteration in a Shiny App

Tags: r, shiny

In my Shiny app, I use a for loop to make two different plots per iteration and I would like the user to be able to click through each one individually.

The count variable keeps count of the number of times the button is clicked however, at each click, two plots are made and only the plot that was rendered last appears.

How would I be able to show every plot using the action button?

```
library(shiny)
server <- function(input, output, session) {          
  # data
  v <- c(9,8,7,8,9,5,6,7,4,3)
  w <- c(3,4,2,3,3,3,2,3,4,5)
  x <- c(1,3,4,6,2,4,6,8,6,3)
  y <- c(4,5,2,4,2,1,2,5,7,8)
  z <- c(5,9,8,6,4,6,8,9,6,7)
  df <- data.frame(v, w, x, y, z)

  # initial plot that will allow user to change parameters (haven't implemented yet)
  output$plot <- renderPlot(plot(df[[1]],df[[2]]))        

  count<-0   # This is the counter which keeps track on button count

  observeEvent(input$run, {
    count <<- count + 1 # Increment the counter by 1 when button is click
    if(count<6){
      # Draw the plot if count is less than 6
      output$plot <- renderPlot(plot(df[[1]],df[[count]],main = count))
      output$plot <- renderPlot(plot(df[[3]],df[[count]],main = count))
    }
    else{
      # Reset the counter if it is more than 5
      count <- 0
    }             
  })
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("run", "Generate"),
  plotOutput("plot")
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: You cound try to use different `outputId`s (`output$plot1` and `output$plot2`)

Comment: Would that show one plot at a time in the same position in the app? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Gregor de Cillia said, you can use different plots.

Edit 1: Show only plot1

```
library(shiny)
server <- function(input, output, session) {          
  # data
  v <- c(9,8,7,8,9,5,6,7,4,3)
  w <- c(3,4,2,3,3,3,2,3,4,5)
  x <- c(1,3,4,6,2,4,6,8,6,3)
  y <- c(4,5,2,4,2,1,2,5,7,8)
  z <- c(5,9,8,6,4,6,8,9,6,7)
  df <- data.frame(v, w, x, y, z)

  # initial plot that will allow user to change parameters (haven't implemented yet)
  # Make two different plots here
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot(plot(df[[1]],df[[2]]))        
  output$plot2 <- renderPlot(plot(df[[3]],df[[1]])) 

  count<-0   # This is the counter which keeps track on button count

  observeEvent(input$run, {
    count <<- count + 1 # Increment the counter by 1 when button is click
    if(count<6){
      # Draw the plot if count is less than 6
      # Update both these plots
      output$plot1 <- renderPlot(plot(df[[1]],df[[count]],main = count))
      # Generate this plot but do not output
      plot2 <- reactive({
        renderPlot(plot(df[[3]],df[[count]],main = count))
      })
    }
    else{
      # Reset the counter if it is more than 5
      count <- 0
    }             
  })
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("run", "Generate"),
  # Output both plots separately
  plotOutput("plot1")
  # Don't show this
  # plotOutput("plot2")
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Edit 2: Based on updated understanding, here's how you can achieve whats required:

```
library(shiny)
server <- function(input, output, session) {          
  # data
  v <- c(9,8,7,8,9,5,6,7,4,3)
  w <- c(3,4,2,3,3,3,2,3,4,5)
  x <- c(1,3,4,6,2,4,6,8,6,3)
  y <- c(4,5,2,4,2,1,2,5,7,8)
  z <- c(5,9,8,6,4,6,8,9,6,7)
  df <- data.frame(v, w, x, y, z)

  # initial plot that will allow user to change parameters (haven't implemented yet)
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot(plot(df[[1]],df[[2]]))

  count<-0   # This is the counter which keeps track on button count

  observeEvent(input$run, {
    count <<- count + 1 # Increment the counter by 1 when button is click
    if(count<6){
      # Draw plot if count < 6

      # In every iteration, first click is an odd number,
      # for which we display the first plot

      if(count %% 2 != 0){
        # Draw first plot if count is odd
        output$plot1 <- renderPlot(plot(df[[1]],df[[count]],main = count))  
      }
      else{
        # Second click is an even number, 
        # so we display the second plot in the previous iteration,
        # hence df[[count - 1]]

        # Draw second plot if count is even
        output$plot1 <- renderPlot(plot(df[[3]],df[[count-1]],main = count))
      }
    }

    else{
      # Reset the counter if it is more than 5
      count <- 0
    }             
  })
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("run", "Generate"),
  # Output plot
  plotOutput("plot1")
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Which plot do you want to show? Also, why are you creating two plots if you have to display only one?

Comment: I want it to iteratively plot k-means, so one plot will be the cluster colours changing and the other plot will be the centroid moving. That's why I need to make two plots per iteration and need only one plot to show up in my app :)

Comment: Yes you can do that. Create second plot as a reactive element and use plotOutput to display only the plot you want to show. See edit.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, is it possible to show both plots but in the same position on the screen and one after the other? I'm happy to send you the actual code if I don't make sense.

Comment: Let me know if I have understood this correctly: 1. The user clicks on the "run" button 2. A plot is displayed 3. After some delay, a different plot is delayed, at the same position 4. This plot stays. 5. User clicks button again, steps 1 to 4 repeat.

Comment: The user clicks 'run' to iterate through all of the plots. So they click and then a plot is shown and then they click again and the next plot is shown etc. In context of k-means, this would mean that the clicking could show the k-means algorithm working by showing the cluster centroids moving and then cluster colours changing.

Comment: This is really confusing. Now you are saying that "So they click and then a plot is shown and then they click again and the next plot is shown etc", meaning one plot is shown. Please write what you want step-wise if you can.

Comment: So 1. The user clicks 2. 2 plots are made in the same iteration of the for loop, only one is shown at the first click 3. The user clicks again 4. The second plot from the first iteration is shown 5. The user clicks again 6. The loop iterates again but only the first plot is shown 7. The user clicks 8. The second plot from that iteration is shown

Comment: Got it. See Edit 2. Let me know if you need any further explanation. Cheers!

Comment: Did this do what was required?